Best High Zoom Lens Configurations
Just wondering which lens configurations are usually best or most optimal for achieving high zoom in the smallest space or with fewest lenses.
E.g Let's say we want to achieve a 1000x magnification. Which lens configurations would achieve this and how large would such a package be? Do you just add typical/smaller lens configurations together or is there a larger specific lens configuration that is suited for such a magnification.
It's fundamentally a physics, geometric optics question, which is why I'm asking it here. Want to understand some of the lens configurations that would be appropriate and the calculations that are related to finding this out.
Can you work backwards to determine a good lens configuration? Or is it more of a case of just going off from what is currently available?
Cheers

I’m voting to close this question because I think that it will be best answered at Photography Stack Exchange.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Is photography stack exchange the best place for this? These high magnifications sound like microscopy objectives. Or for $100000$X, perhaps use an electron microscope instead of optics.

@mmesser314 This question needs more context and information.

Have edited the question, hopefully it's a bit more specific and relevant to this forum
